# Why is $2^4$ congruent to $-1$ modulo $17$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic

I saw an interesting question on Quora ([What remainder is obtained when $2^{2017}+1$ is divided by $17$?](https://www.quora.com/What-remainder-is-obtained-when-2-2017-+1-is-divided-by-17)), but I do not understand the author's solution:

> **Three**, because
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> 2^{2017} + 1 &\equiv 2 \cdot (2^4)^{504} + 1 \\
> &\equiv 2 \cdot (-1)^{504} + 1 \\
> &\equiv 2 \cdot 1 + 1 \\
> &\equiv 3 \pmod{17}
> \end{align}
> $$
>   since $2^4 = 16 \equiv -1$.

Why is $2^4 = 16$ congruent to $-1$ modulo $17$?

Comment: because 16 is a multiple of 17 minus 1. i,e, 16 = 17-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also check it by definition of mod operator.

$a \equiv c \mod b$ is defined as $c = kb + a$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

So $16 = 1 \cdot 17 - 1$

Or using directly the operations:
$$16 \equiv 17-1 \equiv -1 \mod 17$$